# Use apply to add multiple columns (more than 100) of random numbers or other function in R

Tags: r, plyr

I would like to build a function that adds many columns of random variables or other function to a a dataframe. Here I am trying to append it to map data.

```
library(plyr)

add <- function(name, df){
  new.df = mutate(df, name = runif(length(df[,1])))
  new.df
}
```

The function works to add a column of data...

```
add("e", iris) 
iris2<- add("f", iris)
```

The apply does not work...
I am trying to add 26 columns from the list of `letters` so that df$a, df$b, df$c are all random vectors.

```
new <- lapply(letters, add, df = tx)
```

What is the most efficient way to columns from a list of col names?
I would like to later loop through all of the column names in another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear to me, what you want to achieve. This adds multiple columns of random numbers to a data.frame:

```
cbind(iris, 
      matrix(runif(nrow(iris)*5), ncol=5))
```

I don't see a reason to use an `*apply` function.

Comment: this works.. then change names with `colnames(d)[6:10] <- c(letters[1:5])`  but it seems that there is a way to do it another way